# Is there a way in excel to remove certain characters without losing formatting?

Tags: python, excel, vba

So I have a large set of data, within one of the columns is a data field that I’m needing to italicize based on a certain character. If a word begins with a $ and ends with a & it needs to be italicized for instance a cell could contain the following $Text1& (Text2). After formatting I would need it to look like this: *Text1* (Text2). I’ve tried serval diffrent ways to format, but every time I find and replace all the $ and & it either italicizes everything in the cell or nothing at all.

I’ve tried VBA, python, I seem to run into the same issue every time.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that in each cell, there is at most one pair markers ($ &), but not more than one.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim dataRng As Range, c As Range, sTxt
    Dim Index1 As Integer, Index2 As Integer
    Set dataRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3") ' Update as needed
    For Each c In dataRng
        sTxt = c.Text
        Index1 = InStr(sTxt, "$")
        Index2 = InStr(sTxt, "&")
        If Index1 * Index2 > 0 And Index2 > Index1 Then
            c.Value = Replace(Replace(sTxt, "$", ""), "&", "")
            c.Characters(Index1, Index2 - Index1 - 1).Font.Italic = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: in A2 _(Text2)_ is also italic

Comment: see the updated code.